# How to use a usb hotspot as a usb internet modem for ubuntu

Tags: usb-modem, hot-spot

I wanted to know if it is possible to use a Huawei Mobile USB hotspot as an USB modem. The Hotspot model is E5573, on the box it didn't say that ubuntu is supported, it didn't support windows XP too but it worked, the XP computer has no wifi card so we plugged the hotspot into it and the internet on that computer worked, please answer soon

Comment: I am planning to dualboot windows  XP with ubuntu if the answers will say that this thing is possible

Comment: Possibly related: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2447

Answer (score 0):

Hot spots are usually working like wireless access points so I think it should work. Just connect to wifi network which is configured on hotspot. Configuration of hotspot is possible through wifi or USB. Check this [link](https://vxlabs.com/2014/06/15/huawei-e3331-3g-usb-dongle-works-on-ubuntu-14-04-linux/) as well.

Comment: I tried to use my hotspot on tiny linux but it didn't worked, because my pc didn't have wifi card

Comment: The link I posted shows how Huawei E3331 3G USB dongle works on Ubuntu 14.04 Linux, so it is possible that your dongle will work through USB connection.